# Why my puppet can not handle bundle exec?

Tags: puppet

My install file is like this:

```
...
cd /home/work/package/dea_ng
...
bundle install
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
bundle exec rake dir_server:install
```

I'm pretty sure that the last command can run successfully on my client machine, but puppet keep reporting " returned 1 instead of one of [0]" error.

So, here is the install manifest:

```
class dea_ng::install {
  exec { "/bin/bash /home/work/install/dea_ng_install.sh":
    path=>'/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin',
    cwd =>'/home/work/install',
    logoutput => false,
    require =>Class["dea_ng::dea_ngfile"],
    before => Class["dea_ng::service"],
  }
}
```

The problem also happens to my start command which also use bundle exec: after puppet finished dea_ng::install and run dea_ng::service, the command below did not work unless I execute it manually on the client machine.

```
bundle exec rake dir_server:run[config/dea.yml] &
```

I'm really confused about this, it seems like puppet can not handle bundle exec well in my case. Did I missed some env configuration here?

The output of --debug seems no help:

```
Debug: Executing '/bin/bash /home/work/install/dea_ng_install.sh'
Error: /bin/bash /home/work/install/dea_ng_install.sh returned 1 instead of one of [0]
Error: /Stage[main]/Dea_ng::Install/Exec[/bin/bash /home/work/install/dea_ng_install.sh]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: /bin/bash /home/work/install/dea_ng_install.sh returned 1 instead of one of [0]
```

And if I remove the bundle exec line, the shell will success.

Comment: can you run puppet with `--debug` mode and post the few bits prior to the `returned 1` error.

Comment: Can you add print statements or something to your script to see what's different in each of the execution environments?

Comment: @Shakedown Could you give me some tips about what may be different between puppet world and real world in this case? I don't know where to start my debug actually.

Comment: I'm just shooting from the hip really, but...maybe the current environment (`env`) would shed light on something?

Comment: Exciting, I got the error by adding output => true: "couldn't find HOME environment -- expanding `~' ". How to fix that in puppet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real error is found by adding output => true:

```
couldn't find HOME environment -- expanding `~'
```

And this is a know issue in Puppet3, see

> https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/puppet-users/5sk9mJqe4Z0

So add HOME env solves the problem:

environment => "HOME=/root"

Comment: You should mark this as the accepted Answer! Just click that green checkmark in the top left :D